# Adding a new column and calculating ride length from start to finish

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to add a new column to my data set and calculate the `ride_length` from start to finish.

Example of what `glimpse` returns:

```
$ started_at         <chr> "23/01/2021 16:14", 
$ ended_at           <chr> "23/01/2021 16:24",
```

My code:

```
data_trip_cleaned$ride_length <- difftime(data_trip_cleaned$started_at,data_trip_cleaned$ended_at,units = "mins")
```

Error:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: What unit do you want to use for the ride length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error suggests `difftime` can't interpret the format of your date/time automatically. From `?difftime`:

> "Function difftime calculates a difference of two date/time objects
> and returns an object of class difftime with an attribute indicating
> the units."

Are your `started_at` and `ended_at` class = datetime? If not, look at `?as.POSIXct`. Confirm this works like you are expecting:

```
as.POSIXct("23/01/2021 16:24", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
# "2021-01-23 16:24:00 EST"
```

For each column:

```
data_trip_cleaned$started_at <- as.POSIXct(
  data_trip_cleaned$started_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data_trip_cleaned$ended_at <- as.POSIXct(
  data_trip_cleaned$ended_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# or many columns
datetimes <- c("started_at", "ended_at")
t(lapply(df[,datetimes], FUN = function(x) as.POSIXct(x, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")))

# Then calculate difference
data_trip_cleaned$diff <- data_trip_cleaned$ended_at - data_trip_cleaned$started_at

# Alternatively
difftime(data_trip_cleaned$ended_at, data_trip_cleaned$started_at, unit = "secs")
# See ?difftime to see other options for units=
```

Comment: I do not think so ( sorry, still very new to R), I will try this out and give feedback. Thank you so far.

Comment: Thank you,

data_trip_cleaned$started_at <- as.POSIXct(
  data_trip_cleaned$started_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data_trip_cleaned$ended_at <- as.POSIXct(
  data_trip_cleaned$ended_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

This solved my issue, im trying to convert the seconds into minutes now please

Comment: Hi @Frans_Gel, it looks like you comment was cut off? Were you asking how to actually calculate the difference between the two columns? If so, you can try this `data_trip_cleaned$diff <- data_trip_cleaned$ended_at - data_trip_cleaned$started_at` or `difftime(data_trip_cleaned$ended_at, data_trip_cleaned$started_at, unit = "secs")`. See `?difftime` to see other options for `units=`

Comment: Hi @Skaqqs, thank you once again, just had to add the "units" syntax at the end. Working they way I want it to